# Adding a search bar to Google place picker

Tags: java, android

I am using the google place picker detailed [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiAgvbSjKDIAhUGGpIKHRZECDA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fplaces%2Fandroid-api%2Fplacepicker&usg=AFQjCNFuK_XE6WfCw-EoHPYroGDOFFeSYA&sig2=UHtRL-7ZoT6ZwrEpAn_61Q) and I do not see how to add a search bar to the place picker (like google keep has for example) how am I supposed to add a search bar?

Comment: You can't. There is no visible API atm.